# Implicit declaration of snprintf

Tags: c, c99, printf, c89

I noticed that when I compile this [iniparser](https://github.com/ndevilla/iniparser.git) it spits the following warning:

```
 src/iniparser.c:244:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘snprintf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     snprintf(keym, secsize, "%s:", s);
```

The solution was supposedly to add:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

I tried this, but that alone didn't solve the problem. Then I looked into the compile flags inside the Makefile, and found this:

```
 CFLAGS  += -fPIC -Wall -ansi -pedantic
```

If I changed this to:

```
 CFLAGS  += -fPIC -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic
```

It compiled with out a warning. Does this mean that the C90 standard does not include `snprintf` ? Can someone explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: No, it means that the C90 standard doesn't include `snprintf`. Your testing says nothing about `sprintf` since it is not used.

Comment: @Kaz, I meant snprintf. I mistyped it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*`snprintf`* is specified only in C99, unlike *`sprintf`* which is in C90. See `man sprintf` for more information.

Comment: Also watch out for `snprintf` and the wide character `swprintf` having different return value semantics!